# Paginação aparecer em JSF Primafeces Datatable apenas quando tiver mais que uma página

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, paginação

Como fazer para que a paginação apareça apenas quando tiver mais que uma página, utilizando o componente `Datatable` do  `Primefaces` no `JSF`?

Comment: Você esta utilizando JSF puro ou algum framework (Primefaces, Richfaces, Icefaces...)?

Comment: Editei a pegunta e acrescentei o primefaces lá

Comment: Qual versão está usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a documentação do [Primefaces 6.1](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf), você pode utilizar o atributo `paginatorAlwaysVisible` para ocultar caso a tabela não apresente o número de registros necessários para paginação:

Segue uma tradução da documentação:

> **Propriedade**: paginatorAlwaysVisible
>
> **Valor padrão**: true
>
> Define se o
>   componente de paginação deve ser oculto se o contador total de
>   registros é menor que a quantidade de registros por página

Portanto em sua `datatable` utilize o atributo `paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"`